# Micro meter high memory usage

Tags: out-of-memory, spring-boot-actuator, datadog, micrometer, spring-micrometer

We are seeing some of our services (Java <> SpringBoot) getting OOM. On checking heap dump, we found the micrometer library is taking 113MB (around 54% of total heap memory).

```
io.micrometer.statsd.internal.LogbackMetricsSuppressingUnicastProcessor
Jar: io.micrometer:micrometer-core
```

I did some research online and found creating a lot of distinct tags can lead to this issue. However, this is not the case with our services. We are pushing a lot of metrics to data dog but reusing tags all the time.

Comment: Can you add details about how long it takes for an OOM to occur? Also how many metrics are you sending? 1 meter with 2 distinct tags would take about the same as 2 meters. (Internally they are the same thing)

Answer (score 11):

Memory issues like this are often caused by using high cardinality tags.

High cardinality here means that the tag can have a large number of unique values. For example, if you want to attach the `gender` of your users to your metrics, that tag potentially has low cardinality because you might not have a lot of values to choose from. The `userID` on the other hand is high cardinality since every single user will have a unique one.

Having high cardinality tags can result in a huge amount of meters since you have a meter for every unique value which will result in high memory consumption and your metrics backend will experience similar issues too.

Examples for (potentially) high cardinality tags:

- ID of the resource, e.g.: userID
- Email address (basically any user input)
- Request path instead of template (e.g.: it can contain resourceID)

See this article for more details: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/
also see the Micrometer docs: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_tag_values

Do you have high cardinality tags? If so, you can normalize or remove them.